# DNS name resolution with Samba and through a VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, vpn, samba

My problem is about DNS names resolution in case there are two DNS servers separated by a VPN and only one DNS domain name.

Context: two Samba AD DC on each side of the VPN, one forest, one domain, one site, two subnets.
Note that this target configuration is not yet operational since I'm trying to make the DSN names resolution work first through the VPN.

```
+--------------------------+             +--------------------------+
| SUBNET: 192.168.1.0/24   |             | SUBNET: 192.168.2.0/24   |
+--------------------------+             +--------------------------+
| SAMBA AD DC DNS server 1 | --- VPN --- | SAMBA AD DC DNS server 2 |
+--------------------------+             +--------------------------+
| DOMAIN: company.elmts    |             | DOMAIN: company.elmts    |
+--------------------------+             +--------------------------+
| hostname_1_1             |             | hostname_2_1             |
| hostname_1_2             |             | hostname_2_2             |
| ...                      |             | ...                      |
| hostname_1_N1            |             | hostname_2_N2            |
+--------------------------+             +--------------------------+
```

Sedentary machines: have their hostname registered either on SAMBA AD DC DNS server 1 or (exclusive) SAMBA AD DC DNS server 2.

Nomad machines: have their hostname registered on both SAMBA AD DC DNS servers.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
On SAMBA AD DC DNS server 1: 
----------------------------
FQDN: hostname_1_1.company.elmts. / IP: 192.168.1.11 / SEDENTARY
FQDN: hostname_1_2.company.elmts. / IP: 192.168.1.12 / SEDENTARY
...
FQDN: nomad_a.company.elmts.      / IP: 192.168.1.53 / NOMAD
FQDN: nomad_b.company.elmts.      / IP: 192.168.1.54 / NOMAD
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
On SAMBA AD DC DNS server 2:
----------------------------
FQDN: hostname_2_1.company.elmts. / IP: 192.168.2.21 / SEDENTARY
FQDN: hostname_2_2.company.elmts. / IP: 192.168.2.22 / SEDENTARY
...
FQDN: nomad_a.company.elmts.      / IP: 192.168.2.65 / NOMAD
FQDN: nomad_b.company.elmts.      / IP: 192.168.2.66 / NOMAD
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make this work?

For now, if I `ping hostname_2_1` from `hostname_1_1`, the name `hostname_2_1` is not resolved.

Thank you.